# WCF Data Service Client Collection Types

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I've got an EF6 model, and a WCF Data Services service layer to expose it to my WPF client.
When I add the Service Reference to the client, the advanced dialog allows me to choose which Collection and Dictionary types. 
Do I need to change these for WPF?  I think so, there's certainly types in the list that seem more appropriate than the defaults, but I can't find anything the specifically says I need to change things.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to change those for WPF. It depends strictly on what you will do with those lists.
You can see [here](http://jeremybytes.blogspot.ro/2012/03/web-service-proxy-collection-types.html) a little discussion on what you should choose.